# ControllerAdvice annotation in spring 4 is not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

**In spring-mvc.xml:**

```
<beans ...>
     <mvc:annotation-driven/>
     <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />
     <bean class="com.app.controllers.ExceptionController"/>
     ....
</beans>
```

**In GlobalException.java:**

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = "com.exceptions")
public class GlobalException {
    @ExceptionHandler(UserDefinedException.class)
    public ModelAndView processCustomException(UserDefinedException ud) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("exceptionPage");
    mav.addObject("name", ud.getName());
    mav.addObject("message", ud.getMessage());
    return mav;
}
}
```

**In ExceptionController.java:**

```
public class ExceptionController implements Controller {
     @Override
     public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
     throw new UserDefinedException("Custom Exception has occured", "CustomException");
  }
}
```

Ecxception is throwing as `com.exceptions.UserDefinedException: Custom Exception has occured`. But ExceptionHandler method is not called. Whats wrong is this code. I'm using spring 4.3 version.

Comment: are your controller classes in package `com.exceptions` ? because only controller classes in that package will currently be advised. if not, try removing `basePackages`attribute...

Comment: @TommyBrettschneider within the same package.

Answer (score 1):

enable Spring's component scanning in your spring-mvc.xml by adding this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.exceptions" />
```

and remove your obsolete XML configured Spring bean (`<bean class="com.app.controllers.ExceptionController"/>`)

also annotate your controller classes with `@Controller` and add a `@RequestMapping` to your controller methods, e.g. like this:

```
@Controller
public class ExceptionController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/whatever", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
       throw new UserDefinedException("Custom Exception has occured", "CustomException");
    }
}
```

this way, your classes annotated with Spring stereotype annotations (@Component, @Service, @Controller, @Repository) should be found, instantiated and registered as Spring beans by Spring itself at application startup!

Comment: Here my issue is exception throws but its not forwarding to exception page.